# Multiple lines if statements

Tags: php, if-statement

I am checking around 20 variables like the following and I was wondering if there is a faster way (less lines) to do the same:

```
if ($data1 == 1) {
  $res1 = "Yes";
} else {
  $res1 = "No";
}
if ($data2 == 1) {
  $res2 = "Yes";
} else {
  $res2 = "No";
}
if ($data3 == 1) {
  $res3 = "Yes";
} else {
  $res3 = "No";
}
etc..
```

Comment: try `switch` case or iterate it with array

Comment: create array of those variables, pass to a function and again return an array of `yes or no` accordingly

Comment: @M.Hemant that's a pretty good idea actually.. mind if I "steal" and edit my answer with? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways:

1) foreach loop:

```
$array = [$data1, $data2, $data3];

foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
    ${'res'. $key} = ($value == 1 ? 'yes' : 'no');
}
```

Although as Qirel pointed out, this probably isn't the best thing to do. If you need to name new values `$name. $x` then it's probably better as an array:

```
$array = [$data1, $data2, $data3];
$res = [];

foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
    $res[$key] = ($value == 1 ? 'yes' : 'no');
}
```

2) function:

```
function checkVal($value)
{
    return ($value == 1 ? 'yes' : 'no');
}

$res1 = checkVal($data1);
```

3) ternary - not necessarily not repeating code, but it's shorter:

```
$res1 = ($data1 == 1 ? 'yes' : 'no')
$res2 = ($data2 == 1 ? 'yes' : 'no')
$res3 = ($data3 == 1 ? 'yes' : 'no')
```

Comment: The only drawback with your first approach is that its using variable variables - its an indication that something should be arrays instead (which this looks very much like the case from OP). Not much to do with the current data-structure you're presented with, but thought I'd mention it none the less. Personally, I'd probably go for your option 3, or a `switch`.

Answer (score 1):

This should also work -

```
// number of variables to check
$num = 3;
// Loop for checking all the variables as per naming convnetions followed
for ($i = 1; $i <= $num; $i++) {
    // set yes/no depending on the data set
    ${'res' . $i} = ${'data' . $i} == 1 ? 'yes' : 'no';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the context but from what I can see my advice is to create an array of $data1, $data2, $dataN and loop all these values to create another array with all checks

```
$values = [$data1, $data2, $data3, $data4];
$responses = array_reduce($values, function ($a, $b) {
    $a[] = 1 === $b;

    return $a;
}, []);
```